# objective C view is not being loaded on physical device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, xcode4.2

I am using XCode 4.2 to develop an application for iPhone and iPad

I am loading a view using the following function

```
-(IBAction)button{
    ...
    SettingsView *hello ;   
    hello= [[SettingsView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:hello animated:YES];
}
```

on the simulator the view is loaded perfectly . but when I load the app on a real iPhone , I get a white screen and cannot go back to the app ... any reasons ?

Comment: Does it have a .xib file associated with it?

Comment: "Class" is not what you think it is, you should be using SettingsView *hello; instead.

Comment: there is an xib file associated with it yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common cause of this kind of problem is a case mismatch. since you passed `nil` as the name, it'll try to load `SettingsView.nib`. If your file is called `Settingsview.nib` (note the "v"), then that will work on Mac (most of the time, and simulator) but not on iOS. By default, Mac has a case-insensitive filesystem. iOS always has a case-sensitive file system.

---

After you've built for device, go to `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and find your project output. Dig down into the Products directory and make sure that your nib file is really there and named what you expect.

Comment: I have a xib file associated with the class.
I made sure of the case sensitivity and still nothing ...

Answer (score 1):

if no .xib is associated with it then use this code:

```
SettingsView *hello= [[SettingsView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:hello animated:YES];
[hello release];
```

if there is a .xib associated with it

```
SettingsView *hello= [[SettingsView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsView" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:hello animated:YES];
[hello release];
```

Comment: I have an xib file associated with it , I tried the code and still having the same issue ...

Comment: A nice but occasionally confusing feature of UIViewController is that if you pass nil for the nib name, it'll look for a nib whose name matches the name of the class. So a class named "MyViewController" will look for a .xib file named "MyViewController.xib".

Comment: Is the name of your .xib "SettingsView"? And is it connected in Interface Builder to the class SettingsView

Answer (score 0):

try setting view `frame` and `modalPresentationStyle`

```
SettingsView *hello= [[SettingsView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsView" bundle:nil];

hello.view.frame = CGRectMake(<CGFloat x>, <CGFloat y>, <CGFloat width>, <CGFloat height>)
hello.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

[self presentModalViewController:hello animated:YES];
[hello release];
```

And from where (what is self??) are you trying to present a modalviewcontroller??